# 2-dimensional binning with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, feature-engineering

So I have two sets of features that I wish to bin (classify) and then combine to create a new feature. It is not unlike classifying coordinates into grids on a map.

The issue is that the features are not evenly distributed and I would like to use quantiles when binning (like with `pandas.qcut()`) on both features/coordinates.

Is there a better way than doing `qcut()` on both features and then concatenating the result labels?

Comment: I can't think of any.  It seems the absolute appropriate way to do it.  Only thing better would be to have a built in function for it.

Comment: I am wrong... there is something I'd like better

Comment: I am waiting earnestly...

Comment: Putting it together now... don't get too excited, it's merely an extension of the same idea

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***Create a cartesian product categorical.***

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=np.random.rand(20), B=np.random.rand(20)))

           A         B
0   0.538186  0.038985
1   0.185523  0.438329
2   0.652151  0.067359
3   0.746060  0.774688
4   0.373741  0.009526
5   0.603536  0.149733
6   0.775801  0.585309
7   0.091238  0.811828
8   0.504035  0.639003
9   0.671320  0.132974
10  0.619939  0.883372
11  0.301644  0.882258
12  0.956463  0.391942
13  0.702457  0.099619
14  0.367810  0.071612
15  0.454935  0.651631
16  0.882029  0.015642
17  0.880251  0.348386
18  0.496250  0.606346
19  0.805688  0.401578
```

We can create new categoricals with `pd.qcut`

```
d1 = df.assign(
    A_cut=pd.qcut(df.A, 2, labels=[1, 2]),
    B_cut=pd.qcut(df.B, 2, labels=list('ab'))
)

           A         B A_cut B_cut
0   0.538186  0.038985     1     a
1   0.185523  0.438329     1     b
2   0.652151  0.067359     2     a
3   0.746060  0.774688     2     b
4   0.373741  0.009526     1     a
5   0.603536  0.149733     1     a
6   0.775801  0.585309     2     b
7   0.091238  0.811828     1     b
8   0.504035  0.639003     1     b
9   0.671320  0.132974     2     a
10  0.619939  0.883372     2     b
11  0.301644  0.882258     1     b
12  0.956463  0.391942     2     a
13  0.702457  0.099619     2     a
14  0.367810  0.071612     1     a
15  0.454935  0.651631     1     b
16  0.882029  0.015642     2     a
17  0.880251  0.348386     2     a
18  0.496250  0.606346     1     b
19  0.805688  0.401578     2     b
```

You can create the cartesian product categorical with tuples

```
d2 = d1.assign(cartesian=pd.Categorical(d1.filter(regex='_cut').apply(tuple, 1)))
print(d2)

           A         B A_cut B_cut cartesian
0   0.538186  0.038985     1     a    (1, a)
1   0.185523  0.438329     1     b    (1, b)
2   0.652151  0.067359     2     a    (2, a)
3   0.746060  0.774688     2     b    (2, b)
4   0.373741  0.009526     1     a    (1, a)
5   0.603536  0.149733     1     a    (1, a)
6   0.775801  0.585309     2     b    (2, b)
7   0.091238  0.811828     1     b    (1, b)
8   0.504035  0.639003     1     b    (1, b)
9   0.671320  0.132974     2     a    (2, a)
10  0.619939  0.883372     2     b    (2, b)
11  0.301644  0.882258     1     b    (1, b)
12  0.956463  0.391942     2     a    (2, a)
13  0.702457  0.099619     2     a    (2, a)
14  0.367810  0.071612     1     a    (1, a)
15  0.454935  0.651631     1     b    (1, b)
16  0.882029  0.015642     2     a    (2, a)
17  0.880251  0.348386     2     a    (2, a)
18  0.496250  0.606346     1     b    (1, b)
19  0.805688  0.401578     2     b    (2, b)
```

If you were so inclined, you could even declare an ordering for them.

Comment: Looks great. Thanks! Will accept this answer within a reasonable timeframe if no other challengers appear.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using now: `df["bucket"] = list(zip(pd.qcut(df["A"], 10, labels=list(range(10))), pd.qcut(df["B"], 10, labels=list(range(10)))))` based on your answer.